# How to determine which base to use when building a nuro_image?

Tags: bazel

As stated in the title, when I add a new push_image, how do I determine how to specify the base in BUILD file for the nuro_image target? I've seen several different ones in the code base such as

```
base = "//learning/utils:tf_base_image",
```

and

```
base = "@nuro_image//image",
```

what are the differences?

Answer (score 0):

This depends on what dependencies does the binary/image need. If a binary needs Tensorflow as dependency then you want to use the `tf_base_image`.

The idea is similar to lowest common ancestor.
Imagine we are building binary A into an image. Say A has two dependencies B and C, and both B and C depends on Tensorflow.
If A uses `tf_base_image`, then when we build B and C, the dependent Tensorflow library is already included and can be reused. But if we A uses `@nuro_image//image`, then both B and C needs to fetch Tensorflow, thus we end up including the same library twice. As a result, the build becomes slower and we get a larger image.

For better understanding, the definition of `tf_base_image` is here:
https://gitent.corp.nuro.team/Nuro-ai/Nuro/blob/develop/learning/utils/BUILD#L84-L98